# i.e. + subordinate clause

Tags: word-usage, subordinate-clauses, that

Can we directly use a "that-clause" after i.e?

For example:

> The curve follows the same trend, i.e. that the volume increases with increased temperature.

Comment: You don't need the subordinator "that". This is one construction when a 'bare' content clause is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You are already saying "that is," so following it with another "that" is awkward at best.

I would recommend:

The curve follows the same trend: volume increases as temperature increases.

Or, if you must use i.e.:

The curve follows the same trend, i.e., volume increases as temperature increases.

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about using the same word twice in a sentence. Not to mention that *i.e.* doesn't actually contain *that*.

Comment: @PeterShor Sure it does: _id_. It’s just a foreign _that_. I agree that having a subordinator after _i.e._ sounds odd in this case, though it won’t necessarily always be so. Reading it out loud as “in other words” makes for a more reliable test, I think: “It follows the same trend; in other words that volume increases…” is ungrammatical, but “He said that it follows the same trend; in other words, that volume increases…” is fine.

Comment: @Janus: I think it might just depend on whether you think of the text following **i.e.** as applying to the entire preceding statement, or simply a "redefinition"" of ***the same trend*** (in which case I understand it as *[that's to say, the trend **that**] volume increases as temperature*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good point. Reading it like that it sounds unremarkable to me too.

Comment: @Janus: Mind you, I agree with Peter that **i.e.** doesn't actually contain **that**. But then again I've never got worked up over people talking about  **PIN numbers, GPS systems,** and the like.